# How to start multiple memcached servers say on different ports

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memcached

The memcached instance is automatically started on the default port post installation. How to start multiple memcached servers say on different ports (say 11212 or 11213) after rebooting my Ubuntu machine.

sudo apt-get install memcached

ps -ef | grep memcached
memcache 21315     1  0 07:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go over memcached tutorial that explains configuration and troubleshooting:

**Use Memcached for Java enterprise performance**, **Part 1**: Architecture and setup
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2012/120418-memcached-for-java-enterprise-performance.html

**Use Memcached for Java enterprise performance, Part 2**: Database-driven web apps
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2012/120515-memcached-for-java-enterprise-performance-2.html